# Heap sort analysis

Tags: algorithm

In the analysis of heap sort we know that one of the ways to perform heap sort is in two phases.

1. Create a heap i.e., max or min priority queue.
2. Remove the maximum/minimum from priority queue until all elements have been removed

Suppose there are `N` elements. For phase 1 the number of comparisons is `2N` and for one removal the number of comparisons is `2lgN` so for N removals it is `2NlgN` comparisons. So total number of comparisons is `2N + 2NlgN`.

This is my understanding. The book I am reading is Algorithms analysis by Wesis which says:

In the second phase, the `i`th `deletemax` uses at most `2(floor(log i))` comparisons, for a total of at most `2NlogN - O(N)` comparsions (assuming `N >= 2`). Consequently in the worst case, there are at most `2NlogN - O(n)` comparisons for heap sort.

My questions are

1. How did the author conclude that in the second phase, the `i`th `deletemax` uses at most `2(floor(logi))` comparisons?
2. How did the author come up with a total of `2NlogN - O(N)`?

Comment: you should pick a book that does the full analysis. http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Algorithms-Thomas-H-Cormen/dp/0262033844

Comment: @yi_H, he talks about specific book and specific analysis, which may be wrong or OP can't understand it, he knows bases to analyze it.

Comment: well I remember it's an ugly sum which is based on some sum equation explained in the appendix. it's not really complex but also not trivial. I just don't want to pick the book and copy-paste the whole paragraph.

Comment: For 1), I think the wording is backward but the conclusion is the same.  The heap shrinks every time you do a deletemax.  So after `i` deletes, the next one will only have `(N-i)` items to deal with, so `2(floor(lg(n-i)))` comparisons.  After the  `N-1`th delete, there will only be 1 item.  Over the N items, you have the series `N,N-1,N-2,...1`.  But the order doesn't really matter for the analysis, you could just as easily consider it as `1,2,...N`, which is the way it is stated.